# How to query a table created by another query?

Tags: mysql

So I have a table, `users`, with user `Balance`s and `ID`s.
With the below query, I get the table I need – which sorts the users by their balance.

`SET @row_num=0; SELECT (@row_num:=@row_num+1) AS serial_num, ID, Balance FROM users ORDER BY Balance DESC;` - which returns the following table:

[Resulting MYSQL table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvsR9.png)

**How would I find the `serial_num` of a specific user from the above table by `ID`?**

I've tried `SELECT * FROM ( the query above ) WHERE ID = "...";` but I must be getting something wrong with the syntax and I don't quite understand how I would implement a sub-query here. 
Cheers

Comment: Can you try adding the where clause in the nested sub-query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had actually just 1 like mistake which lead to an uninitialized variable. Replace

```
SET @row_num=0;
```

with

```
SET @row_num:=0;
```

A little shorter version which can be run in one query would be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
   SELECT ID, Balance, @row := @row + 1 AS serial_num
   FROM users 
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row := 0) r
   ORDER BY Balance DESC
) tmp
WHERE serial_num = 2
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d9350/18)